# Material UI Appbar not scrolling together with page

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In this example (someone else's code sandbox):
https://codesandbox.io/s/rmll8r8qvp?file=/index.js

When the screen size width is very small (~136 px width), the "account" icon is unable to be accessed. Is there a way to scroll the app bar together with the page when below certain width?

Comment: Try the prop ```position="fixed" ```

Comment: Already being used in that example, yet the account icon is still unable to be accessed.